# Examples of group actions on statistical manifolds

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, group-actions, homogeneous-spaces

A statistical manifold $(M,g,\nabla)$ is a Riemannian manifold with a torsion-free *affine* connection $\nabla$ such that $\nabla g$ is symmetric in all entries. Equivalently, there is a dual affine connection $\nabla^*$ such that $X(g(Y,Z)) = g(\nabla_X Y,Z) + g(Y,\nabla^*_X Z)$, with $X,Y,Z \in \mathcal{X}(M)$.
In the preprint [Furuhata, Inoguchi, and Kobayashi - A characterization of the alpha-connections on the statistical manifold of normal distributions](https://arxiv.org/abs/2005.13927) there is a definition of *homogenous statistical manifold* (Definition 1.4.1). One of the conditions says that the action of $G$ (by isometries) is affine with respect to $\nabla$. I am not familiar with actions on statistical manifolds. I am supposing that it means that, as a map $\nabla : \mathcal{X}(G) \times \mathcal{X}(G) \to \mathcal{X}(G)$, the connection verifies $\nabla_X Y = (h^{-1})_* (\nabla_{h_* (X)} h_*(Y))$ (?). Here $\nabla_X Y \mathrel{:=} \nabla(Y,X)$ and $h_*$ indicates the tangent action induced by the left translation by an element $h$ in $G$.

Thus there is an induced quotient homogeneous statistical structure $(G/H, \bar g, \bar \nabla)$, right?. Besides the examples presented in that paper, are there other (more geometrically inspired) known examples of homogeneous non-trivial statistical manifolds?
The structure is said to be trivial if $\nabla = \nabla^*$ and in that case they coincide with the Levi–Civita connection, otherwise it is non-trivial.